# Angular Filters Not Working In a Component

Tags: angularjs, components, angular-filters

I've got a feeling I'm missing something deceptively simple here... I created an app on a tight deadline, so I created the controllers, filters and even a static service all in one app.js file.

I'm now working on breaking the app apart using the .component() model and creating a better standalone service to get live data from a db. Converting to components has been working well, but I'm hitting a snag with the filters. They still reside in the original app.js, and worked fine when the controllers were defined there, but now the filters don't seem to be working within the new component templates. When I apply a filter to a value in the component template, the value doesn't seem to be returned and nothing appears on the page.

Example filter:

```
app.filter('commaDelimitedNumber', function(){
    return function(val){
        var v = (val !== undefined) ? val.toString() : '0';
        return v.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
    };
});
```

Call from a component:

```
<div>{{ $ctrl.metric.shortVals[$ctrl.currentFilter] | display:[$ctrl.currentFilter] | commaDelimitedNumber }}</div>
```

An extra note... The component containing the filter is a sub-component using this structure:

```
angular.module (index.html including the app.js file)
   <metrics-component> (component .js file with template html file which contains...)
      <metrics-list-component> (component .js file with template html file which contains...)
         <metric-component> (component .js file with template html file which contains...)
            <div>{{ 12345678 | commaDelimitedNumber }}</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by *sub-component*? How do you merge/include these files in HTML? If the filter is not found, an exception should be thrown. Are there any errors in JS console?

Comment: No errors in the console. by "sub-component" I mean that the component is a child of a component that is a child of a component that is in index.html. The components are "merged" through the .component() structure at runtime. I'll revise the example above to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... I found the issue. It wasn't the component/filter combo that was the problem, it was a piece of data I didn't carry through the components. I was expecting an overcomplicated problem and it wound up being an oversight. Oops!